# TinyGet not working after enforcing TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, iis

We use TinyGet.exe to hit certain URLs in a web application at scheduled times.
I am setting up a new environment and this time I have disabled TLS 1.1 and older based on recommendations from ssllabs.com.

So right now it's just TLS 1.2 that is permitted by our IIS instance.

When using a command like this we are getting errors...

```
tinyget -srv:myapplicationurl.app -uri:/Scheduler/ProcessQueue -s:4

ERROR: 0x80090331 : [slib]: Could not AcquireCredentialsHandle
ERROR: 0x80090331 : Failed to AcquireCredentials()
```

My gut is telling me it is probably because TLS 1.2 is not supported by TinyGet. Can someone confirm this and if so maybe offer an alternative approach?

Comment: Anything about IIS 6 is end of life. Stack Overflow is not a place for tool recommendation and there isn't an alternative out there. You have to write your own with C# or PowerShell.

Comment: So if it's confirmed that TLS1.2 is not supported then Powershell would be an alternative.

Comment: There is neither source code nor documenation on TinyGet's supported TLS versions, so I wonder how you might get any confirmation.

Comment: I also think this may be because TinyGet does not support TLS1.2, and TinyGet is no longer updated. There is also very little introduction to TinyGet in the official Microsoft documentation. You can also try WCAT, for more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc656685(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

All my investigation tells me that TLS 1.2 or greater is not supported by the Tinyget utility.